# check if the row selected is newly added

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a jgrid with inline editing, when i click on "+" in the pager button it adds a row in editable mode. When the row is in editable mode i click on "+" again at tht time i want to show a message saying "the grid is in edit mode please save it".

```
document.getElementById('partnerGrid_iladd').onclick = function() {

  var rowid = jQuery("#partnerGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
  var edited = "";
  var ind = jQuery("#partnerGrid").getInd(rowid, true);
  if (ind != false) {
    edited = $(ind).attr("editable");
  }

  if (edited === "1") {
    alert("There is an row in editable mode  ,Please save the row before adding another row");
    return;

  }
}
```

But this gets fired after a row is added in the grid and the row is in added mode.. So i want to check if the row is a new one if the row is new one i don't want to throw error on click of +.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement your requirement. You don't posted enough details about what you do, but because you test `editable` attribute I can guess that you write about the "+" button added by `inlineNav`. In the case jqGrid calls `addRow` on the click on the Add button. The method `addRow` have `beforeAddRow` callback and `jqGridInlineBeforeAddRow` event which you can use. The callback/event should return `false` to prevent adding new row and starting the editing. Moreover you can use `savedRow` parameter of jqGrid to test whether some other row is in editing mode. You can use `getGridParam` to get `"savedRow"` parameter. The returned value is array of saved rows with the values before starting editing. Thus if the `length` of the array grater as 0 then some other row is still editing.

Comment: How can i add these events after grid is created , i tried with setgridparam its not working

Comment: @Ekata: I'm not sure which events you mean. You can use `$("#gridid").bind("jqGridInlineBeforeAddRow", function (e, options) {... return false;})` for example to use `jqGridInlineBeforeAddRow` event. You can bind the event to the grid even before the grid will be created (or after it was created).